# Whats the advantage of multivalued fields over a single CSV field in solr search?

Tags: solr

I am new to Solr and in the process of designing a solr shema for my next project.

My question is what is/are the advantages(efficiency/execution time etc.) of a multivalued field when cmpared to a single field holding multivalues in a CSV format.

For eg.: Lets consider a field called car. So which one is better if i am designing a solr search engine. Please ignore the schema/doc syntax.

```
<Car>A</Car>
<Car>B</Car>
<Car>C</Car>
```

OR

```
<Car> A,B,C</Car>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple values for the field, you should probably go for Multivalued fields.

Multivalued things can prevent wrong matches.
e.g. If you have a document with multiple authors. A B & C D
If you index it as a single field it may happen that when u search for phrase match "B C" (or with small slop) it will match this document as the words would appear in line.

Multivalued fields will prevent such matches with a proper position increment values.

Also, multivalued fields will allow you to filter the results correctly.
`q=authores:"B C"` or much better  or use the tags to filter out results like `q=query&fq=authors:"B C"` which will take advantage of the filter cache and add to the query performance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main advantage is the design of your index. If you put this 3 values into a single field, this field represents after the search 1 value. If you use multivaluefields, for each value a new field will be created and displayed. What sense does this have:

Imagine, you want to expand your index. The value of one of new fields could be something like

```
<LengthOfCar>5,0</LengthOfCar>
```

If you now want to work with your given result, you aren´t able to tell what value is multivalued and which isn´t, because you seperate it all by ",". Maybe for you it will be clear, but all other user won´t get the difference. The result will be for a single field:

```
<doc>
<str name="Car">A,B,C</str>
</doc>
```

The result for your multivalued field would be:

```
<doc>
<arr name="Car">
<str>A</str>
<str>B</str>
<str>C</str>
</arr>
</doc>
```

As you can see, the result for the multivalued field is much more meaningful. AND its in a way much easier to work with it (maybe you want to use xslt or something).

According to your question of efficiency: I don´t think there will be any difference of the performance and execution time. Solr is extremly fast, you won´t even notice the difference if there is any difference.

So I recommend you to use multivalued fields, because there are 3 different values for 1 field.

Answer (score 0):

By using multivalued field you will have more flexibility. You can search and filter results  with the specific value as follows if you use multivalued field.

```
q=car:A or fq=car:A
```

As performance there shouldn't be any difference when indexing/searching multivalued field and singlevalued field.

In [this mail post](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/AAfXf5z712YsEs7WCq7z) they said that multivalued field affects facet performance.

> MultiValued field always uses the TermEnum algorithm rather than the
>   FieldCache algorithm.
>
> TermEnum is good for a limited number of different indexed terms in
>   the field, and allows multiple terms per field per document, while
>   FieldCache is good for a large number of indexed values relative to
>   the number of documents, and only allows a single term per field per
>   document.

Comment: I think his example fields are within 1 document, so normally his choice won´t affect the result of the query. Depends on the configuration of the field.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, using a CSV content field, you will have to tokenized the all by yourself to get a good search result. With multivalued fields, you will get this done by Solr. Take a look at the example

CSV field

```
<str name="Pet">Dog,Cat</name>
```

If you wanna search for all documents containing a pet of the type 'Dog', you will have to configured your CSV field type in such a way that it tokenizes the text for you. So, you can search for 'Dog' or 'Cat' separately.

Now with a multivalued filed

```
<arr name="Pet">
<str>Dog</str>
<str>Cat</str>
</arr>
```

You don't need any additional code to search for 'Dog'.

Another point is that you can't use a CSV field for faceting. Take a look at http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters